# Is there any other CDN than Amazon which supports hadoop?

Tags: cdn, amazon, amazon-ec2

I need know about CDN which offers to store HDFS .
I know amazon offers such service but i am looking out if some others are giving some better service , additional features or cheaper service.
Please suggest me some options .

Comment: What do you mean by "offers to store HDFS"? Also, Amazon Elastic MapReduce uses Hadoop, but Amazon's CDN (CloudFront) does not. As toomanyairmiles' answer points out, Hadoop isn't suited to CDN storage.

Comment: I meant , on which CDN I can establish my HDFS & store hadoop mapreduce data.

Comment: Still not sure what you mean by establishing an HDFS on a CDN, but Amazon Web Services only allows you to use CloudFront to distribute your MapReduce _results_. You can pretty much do the same with just about any other CDN. If you're looking for a cloud platform to host a Hadoop app, then that's separate from the CDN.

Answer (score 2):

[From the Cloudera forums](http://getsatisfaction.com/cloudera/topics/hadoop_for_content_delivey_network)

*Hadoop HDFS is optimized for large streaming operations and sacrifices certain features - notably low latency file access - to simplify some implementation details. This makes it less than ideal for a CDN storage layer. That said, HBase, a column oriented data store which sits on top of HDFS and provides low latency, random reads, might be interesting to you. HBase is now a top level project at Apache. More information on HBase is available at http://hbase.apache.org/. In our next release, CDH3, we will be supporting HBase as part of our standard suite.*

*Note that Hadoop does not span data centers very well so you'd have to run discreet clusters in each of your locations. From the sounds of it, this is what you were intending anyway, but it's worth calling out.*

*Hope this helps [Eric Sammer, Cloudera Employee](http://getsatisfaction.com/people/eric_sammer)*